# Twilio Android SDK HelloMonkey does not work

Tags: android, twilio

I tried the **Twilio SDK** sample *HelloMonkey* and the app is failing with the exception:  `NoClassDefError trying to instantiate com.twilio.example.hellomonkey.MonkeyPhone`. I am using eclipse. Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: The default project setup does not select all the Android dependencies. In eclipse select the project right click and select "Properties" -> "Java Build Path". Select the "Order and Export" tab and select all the Android dependencies. Also, move the "gen" path above "src". Build and launch the application.

Comment: Hi Check my answer from the below question,You will get to know how Twillio works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971536/i-am-working-with-twilio-android-sdk-when-i-click-on-hangup-button-always-getti/25616088#25616088

Answer (score 1):

The default project setup does not select all the Android dependencies. In eclipse select the project right click and select "Properties" -> "Java Build Path". Select the "Order and Export" tab and select all the Android dependencies. Also, move the "gen" path above "src". Build and launch the application