# I am working with Twilio android SDK, When i click on hangup button always getting error ?not able to disconnect the call after dialing?

Tags: android, twilio

I have successfully integrated Twilio SDK for android but when i am trying to make call with it its not connecting and showing error message in logcat i am getting following errors:

```
1) Failed to hangup call due to error code: 70015, message: pjsua_call_hangup(): Object already exists (PJ_EEXISTS) 

2) Connection disconnected with error code 31000 and message Generic error 

this both errors occurs when i am calling disconnect method if i comment this method then my calling is working fine and i make call but if i call this method phone.disconnect(), i am getting error shown as above. 

This is my methods which i am using to make calls and to disconnect the calls.
```

////// To Make Calls

```
public void connect(String phoneNumber) { 
Map parameters = new HashMap(); 
parameters.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber); 
connection = device.connect(parameters, null /* ConnectionListener */); 
if (connection == null) 
Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection"); 
}
```

// To Disconnect Phone

```
public void disconnect() { 
if (connection != null) { 
connection.disconnect(); 
connection = null; // will null out in onDisconnected() 
if (basicConnectionListener != null) 
basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnecting(); 
} 
}
```

and on my OnClick event:

```
public void onClick(View view) { 
if (view.getId() == R.id.dialButton) 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dialing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
phone.connect("PHONE NUMBER"); 
if (view.getId() == R.id.hangupButton) 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Disconnected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
phone.disconnect(); 

Please suggest me and help me because i tried all possible thing for hangout but still not able to solve it.Thanks in advance. ![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing same problem. if you got the solution please post it here

Answer (score 6):

I am sharing my working class for [twilio SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) setup.

This the calls which is working perfectly for me.I would like to share my class so any one can take reference of it.

This is the Base class which handle all the events of twillio Calling and Disconnecting the call.

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.twilio.client.Connection;
    import com.twilio.client.Connection.State;
    import com.twilio.client.ConnectionListener;
    import com.twilio.client.Device;
    import com.twilio.client.DeviceListener;
    import com.twilio.client.PresenceEvent;
    import com.twilio.client.Twilio;

    public class MonkeyPhone implements Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener, ConnectionListener {
        private static final String TAG = "MonkeyPhone";
        private Device device;
        private Connection connection;
        private final Context context;
        private BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener;
        private BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener;
        private Connection pendingIncomingConnection;
        InputMethodManager imm;
        private boolean speakerEnabled;
        private boolean muteEnabled;

        public interface BasicConnectionListener {
            public void onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();

            public void onConnectionConnecting();

            public void onConnectionConnected();

            public void onConnectionFailedConnecting(Exception error);

            public void onConnectionDisconnecting();

            public void onConnectionDisconnected();

            public void onConnectionFailed(Exception error);
        }

        public interface BasicDeviceListener {
            public void onDeviceStartedListening();

            public void onDeviceStoppedListening(Exception error);
        }

        public MonkeyPhone(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            Twilio.initialize(context, this /* Twilio.InitListener */);
        }

        public void setListeners(BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener, BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener) {
            this.basicConnectionListener = basicConnectionListener;
            this.basicDeviceListener = basicDeviceListener;
        }

        /* Twilio.InitListener method */
        @Override
        public void onInitialized() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Twilio SDK is ready");
            try {
                // String capabilityToken =
                // HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");
                String capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("http:------/auth.php");

                device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain capability token: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        /* Twilio.InitListener method */
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Twilio SDK couldn't start: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() {
            if (device != null)
                device.release();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }

        // To Make Calls

        public void connect(String phoneNumber) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Dialing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            String capabilityToken;
            try {
                // capabilityToken =
                // HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");
                capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");

                device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                device.disconnectAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection = device.connect(parameters, null /* ConnectionListener */);
            if (connection == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
            }
        }

        // To Disconnect Phone
        public void disconnect() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Call Disconnected...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
                connection = null; // will null out in onDisconnected()

                if (basicConnectionListener != null)
                    basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnecting();
            }
        }

        public void setSpeakerEnabled(boolean speakerEnabled) {
            if (speakerEnabled != this.speakerEnabled) {
                this.speakerEnabled = speakerEnabled;
                updateAudioRoute();
            }
        }

        private void updateAudioRoute() {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerEnabled);
        }

        public void setMuteEnabled(boolean muteEnabled) {
            if (muteEnabled != this.muteEnabled) {
                this.muteEnabled = muteEnabled;
                updateAudioRouteForMute();
            }
        }

        private void updateAudioRouteForMute() {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(muteEnabled);
        }

        public State status() {
            connection.getState();
            State statusHere = connection.getState();
            return statusHere;
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Connection arg0) {
            updateAudioRoute();
            updateAudioRouteForMute();
            if (basicConnectionListener != null) {
                basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnected();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnecting(Connection arg0) {
            if (basicConnectionListener != null) {
                basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnecting();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection) {
            if (inConnection == connection) {
                connection = null;
                if (basicConnectionListener != null)
                    basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnected();
            } else if (inConnection == pendingIncomingConnection) {
                pendingIncomingConnection = null;
                if (basicConnectionListener != null)
                    basicConnectionListener.onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection, int arg1, String inErrorMessage) {
            if (inConnection == connection) {
                connection = null;
                if (basicConnectionListener != null)
                    basicConnectionListener.onConnectionFailedConnecting(new Exception(inErrorMessage));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPresenceChanged(Device arg0, PresenceEvent arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartListening(Device arg0) {
            if (basicDeviceListener != null) {
                basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStartedListening();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopListening(Device arg0) {
            if (basicDeviceListener != null) {
                basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStoppedListening(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopListening(Device arg0, int arg1, String arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean receivePresenceEvents(Device arg0) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

You can use this class like:

```
  private MonkeyPhone phone;
  //On create
  phone = new MonkeyPhone(getApplicationContext());

  //On Call Button Click

  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnCallHere) {

            phone.connect(newContact);  

        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnDisconnectHere) {

            phone.disconnect();

        }
```

Comment: Sometimes my app crahses on `connection = device.connect(parameters, null /* ConnectionListener */);` can you please help me in it?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Hello, Sometimes it happens because device Failed to create a new connection.so it will get crash.Try to use above class which I have created,It is working perfect for me in all cases.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested it for 15 times and its not crashing anymore. i just added this line in my try catch block `device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);`

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Great to hear that my answer is usefull to you.you can aceept my answer if you feel it is helpful.Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot accept your answer because this question is asked by you. So, I just up-voted to this answer.

Comment: @PriyankBhojak hey bro, I need you help once again in the case of incoming call.

Comment: Hi , I am getting the following error. Please help to resolve this.  "Connection disconnected with error code 31203 and message No valid account"

Comment: @Nidhi Hey, This code works like charm for me,I think there is some issue with your Token at Twillio account Please check your Token and Account setting may be this can help you.

Comment: @PriyankBhojak I have used the same code , just replace http://------/mobile/auth.php with https://myTwilioHerokuApp.com/token to get the capability token. and on my twilio user account, i am setting voice url as https://myTwilioHerokuApp.com/call . Am i doing something wrong? I am just following the guidelines of the link 
"https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/setup"

Comment: Hi. I have fixed the above mentioned issue using my rest credentials . The problem was due to test credentials. Now on dialling any number , i am getting voice message like ,"Thank you for using your demo account , please upgrade your full account to remove this message ."

Comment: @Nidhi Cool, I told you this issue is related to Account setting, Are you able to make calls now? It should work now.

Comment: @PriyankBhojak Now on dialling any number , i am getting the voice message mentioned in my previous comment . Do i need to upgrade my account to make and test real call?

Comment: @Nidhi you need to upgrade your account for this.You can not do live call on any number with test account.You have to ask for live account credentials to make live calls on numbers.

Comment: @PriyankBhojak Sir, actually i need to check masked phone numbers functionality . Is it not possible to test this before upgrading my account (free trial without charging money) ?

Comment: @Nidhi Don't have much idea as in my case I had live account but Yes,Twilio provides some trial numbers, Check this link hope that will help you https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work

Comment: @Nidhi Happy to help you :)

Comment: @PriyankBhojak  i m getting issue `pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]` and `pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=403 (Forbidden)` could tell me ,how to make it working ?

Comment: @YogeshSeralia status 403 or Error - 20403 means "The account lacks permission to access the Twilio API. Typically this means the account has been suspended or closed. For assistance, please contact support@twilio.com."

Comment: @YogeshSeralia this guy is facing same issue it occurs because your password not set properly check the link hope this will help you : http://pbxinaflash.com/community/index.php?threads/forbidden-wrong-password-on-authentication-for-register.9103/

Comment: @PriyankBhojak please tell me that when i am hitting the api of twilio for making a call ...it succeeds in it and when i do same with android app....this `SIP registr. failed` problem comes

Comment: @YogeshSeralia problem is not in your API calls,This issue occurred due to wrong credentials,You app is not able to authenticate properly that's why its failing to register.check your credentials properly and then try it should work.