# TWILIO call issue due to 2 missing digit

Tags: android, twilio

I am working on an Android application that uses Twilio to make phone calls and to send SMS.

While making a call I get the IVRS message "Your call cannot be completed because of two missing digits".

The FROM number is "+18669135337" and TO number is "(949) 439-7570" or "+19494397570"

What could be the reason thats causing this issue?

This is the code snippet thats making the call

```
public void connect(String toNumber, ConnectionListener listener) {

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Log.e(TAG, "Calling from " + mFromNumber);
    Log.e(TAG, "Calling to " + toNumber);

    Log.e(TAG, "mDevice State is  " + mDevice.getState());

    parameters.put(Constants.KEY_TO_NUMBER, toNumber);
    parameters.put(Constants.KEY_FROM_NUMBER, mFromNumber);

    mConnection = mDevice.connect(parameters, listener);
    Log.e(TAG, "Connection status " + mConnection);
    if (mConnection == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: Can we have a look at your code?

Comment: I  used the BasicPhone sample code provided along with the TWILIO SDK, its also saying the same message

Comment: Hello,@sansid1983 Try my answer from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971536/i-am-working-with-twilio-android-sdk-when-i-click-on-hangup-button-always-getting this is the complete setup with Twilio SDK. and its working fine for me.Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: This is the response from the TWILIO App Monitor <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="women">Please wait while we connect your call</Say>
    <Say voice="women">Your call can not be complited, Due to missing numbers.</Say>
</Response>